# vs code throws bogus errors in typescript code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VS Code falsly raises errors in my TypeScript code. Those warnings seem unconnected.

## Examples

### No `length` property

```
const str : string = "foo";
const num : number = str.length;     // <- length underlined in red
```

VS Code is complaining that `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string'.`

### No `Readonly<...>`

```
type Foo = Readonly<{bar: 42}>     //  <- Readonly underlined in red
```

VS Code Error message: `Cannot find name 'Readonly'`

## Versions

Versions:

- VS Code: 1.33

  Node: 10

  Typescript: 3.4.5

All my packages and VS Code are up to date.
Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Ensure you're not compiling with `--noLib` and check the value of `--lib` (see [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).

Comment: The version of TS that you provide is the one use by vs code or the one installed in your local machine ?